# Duvidas de ACL com node.js!

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, acl

Pessoal estou tentando aplicar Authorização(ACL) utilizando o plugin npm "node_acl" em uma aplicação Node.js com express, estou tentando implementar como explica na documentação.. porem estou tendo dificuldades para aplicar isso na pratica.. tenho o seguinte código em um arquivo projectController.js

```
import express from 'express';
import authMiddleware from '../middlewares/auth';
import mongoose from '../../database';

const router = express.Router();

let acl = require('acl');
acl = new acl(new acl.mongodbBackend(mongoose.connection.db, 'acl_'));

acl.allow("admin", "/projects", "*");

router.use(authMiddleware);
router.use(acl.middleware());

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ 
    ok: true, 
    user: req.userId
  })
});

export default (app) => app.use('/projects', router);
```

Errei em algo?

Obrigado!